# Looping different URLs with AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using [Simple HTML DOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) to parse HTML web page elements via URL. Here is my code to extract some texts in a website.

```
while($from_page <= $to_page){
    $html = file_get_html('http://derp.com/page/'.$from_page.'');
    $protip[] = $html->find('div.class',0)->children(2)->plaintext;
    var_dump($protip);

    $from_page++;
}
```

The problem with this snippet is when I input a high number in `$to_page`, php will return an exceeding execution time error as it loops endlessly.

Can I avoid this by using AJAX call by passing the URL as the parameter in it? If so, I couldn't find any way to achieve it because in my case here, I'm using an external function to parse a url.

Answer (score 2):

[`set_time_limit(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) , 0 means no limit.

Also you can edit the php.ini `max_execution_time` or using `ini_set` to modify.

To prevent the memory leak issue, recommended add [`unset($html);`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm#memory_leak) before `$from_page++;`

Answer (score 1):

You can increase PHP execution max time

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Don't understand the part about AJAX but doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Is it possible that this method may lead to resource hogging?

Comment: You are not hogging resource until there's no more resource ^^ And each PHP script is executed in parallel. What is the complete case?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do or if there is requirements you didn't say. Depending my answer may be rubbish!

Comment: Your answer is okay. I just thought that it's taking so long to load the page if I set it to a higher value. Is this normal for such case, because I'm looping through 'alive' links. Maybe I should put a loading bar to see the progress. Thanks for your suggestion :)